# Flutter: How I can get name of the previous route?

Tags: flutter

There is a situation.

My SomePageWidget(stateful) depends on a previous route.

If previous route is X - I wanna show button with text "hi".
If previous route is Y - I wanna show button with text "bye".

The question is - how can I access previous route name in my SomePageWidget build method?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data using Navigator. Here is the simple exam

```
//First Page

//variable to store data
var _data;


//button to navigate next page
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    _data = _handle(context);
    //check data whether X or Y and proceed
  },
  child: ...
);

//a method that can handle the data sent from next page
dynamic _handle(BuildContext context) async{
  final data = await Navigator.push( context,
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Page2()),
           );
  return data;
}


//Second Page
//button to navigate previous page
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context,'X');//send X or Y depends on your page.
  },
  child: ...
);
```

_handle method is async, so it will listen the Navigator.pop() method where it is triggered. After that returns a data you send.

Comment: That is the thing. I wanna on Second Page understand what the previous route was :)

Comment: in this case previous page is the page which the route begins. Page1 = prev, Page2 = next

Comment: for more info check this link: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data